# Typing Text effect not working

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script to take an array of strings, split them by characters, and print them out to the screen. This is what I have and for some reason it is not doing anything. Any ideas?

```
function autowrite() {
        var write_text=["Your Memories","Your Thoughts","Your Photos"];
        var split_text = Array();
        var i;
        var c;
        for(i=0; i < write_text.length; i++)
        {
            split_text[i] = write_text[i].split("");
            for(c=0; i < split_text.length[i]; i++)
            {
                alert(split_text[i][c]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is using the variable from the first loop.

You need to check and increment `c`, not `i`.

Also, the expression `split_text.length[i]` is wrong; you need to get the `i`<sup>*th*</sup> element of the `split_text` array, not of the `length` property.

Change it to

```
        for(c=0; c < split_text[i].length; c++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(c=0; i < split_text.length[i]; i++) 
            { 
                alert(split_text[i][c]); 
            }
```

replace i with c in i <   and i++   and split_text.length[i];  with split_text[i].length;